# Stored procedure SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, date

I have two tables:

Patient(patientId, patientDOB),

PatientMedCon(conditionId, *patientId)*

I want to create a stored procedure where I type in a conditionId and I will get a list with all the patients with this conditionId but they have to be grouped into three groups (0-12 years old, 13-20 years old and >20 years old). How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick, really depends on how you want it grouped and your potential record count. Also it's worth noting the example below can be achieved with a single query and a case statement instead but this potentially gives you more ideas....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PatientByCondition] 
         @ConditionID Int
AS

-- First Group < 0 - 12.
SELECT P.PatientID, P.PatientDOB, '0 - 12' AS AgeGroup
FROM Patient P
    ,PatientMedCon PMC

WHERE P.PatientID = PMC.PatientID
AND PMC.ConditionID = @ConditionID
AND DATEDIFF(YY ,P.PatientDOB, GETDATE()) <= 12

UNION ALL
-- Second Group 13 - 20.
SELECT P.PatientID, P.PatientDOB, '13 - 20' AS AgeGroup
FROM Patient P
    ,PatientMedCon PMC

WHERE P.PatientID = PMC.PatientID
AND PMC.ConditionID = @ConditionID
AND DATEDIFF(YY ,P.PatientDOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 13 AND 20

UNION ALL
-- Over 20s.
SELECT P.PatientID, P.PatientDOB, '> 20' AS AgeGroup
FROM Patient P
    ,PatientMedCon PMC

WHERE P.PatientID = PMC.PatientID
AND PMC.ConditionID = @ConditionID
AND DATEDIFF(YY ,P.PatientDOB, GETDATE()) > 20
```

Comment: OK. But since I use oracle, will datediff and getdate() work??

Comment: Ah right, sorry I don't use Oracle much these days. No you will have to use Date - DOB to get the Age (top of my head). As for the GETDATE() command I think it's SysDate on Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your help :). One quick question though, I actually want the procedure to display the number of patients (and not the Ids). Do I just use COUNT(P.patientId) instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to provide the database you are using.

In Postgresql 9.0 & greater you could just use a query

Example Query:
    select Patient.patientId, 
    case when EXTRACT(year from AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) < 13 then '0-12'
         when EXTRACT(year from AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) > 12 and EXTRACT(year from   AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) < 21 then '13-20' else '>20' end
    from Patient, PatientMedCon
    where Patient.patientId = PatientMedCon.patientId
    and PatientMedCon.conditionId = %YOur Condition ID Goes here%
    ;

Example SRF

create type PatientsWithCondition as (patientId varchar, ageBracket varchar(4));
 create function GetPatientsWithCondition() returns setof PatientsWithCondition as 'select Patient.patientId, PatientMedCon.conditionId
    case when EXTRACT(year from AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) < 13 then '0-12'
         when EXTRACT(year from AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) > 12 and EXTRACT(year from   AGE(NOW(), Patient.patientDOB)) < 21 then '13-20' else '>20' end
    from Patient, PatientMedCon
    where Patient.patientId = PatientMedCon.patientId
    ;' language 'sql';